# My qrcode scanner not able to scan specific URL containing special character

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, zbar-sdk

I am able to scan all qrcodes for the urls however some urls containing special characters such as "%20" are not getting scanned and it crashes the app. I am using ZBarSDK for scanning and ZBarReaderView is the scanner.

`http://www.winlogisticsmedia.com/images/bigkmr%20end%20sale.jpg` is the URL which when made on qrcode, my app crashes and it shows the below window.

[image: Crash Window]

P.S: One more thing is that I think on which I am getting the scanning report (text) is a nsstring. Is there any chance relating to it as its an string and the text consists of numerics and special characters?

[image: crash report of thread]

Comment: Can you show us the threads that are being called when it crashes? (On the left hand part of your screen where you see "Thread 1" in your screenshot above (this appears WHEN the app crashes) click the areas that say "6 - ..." "7 - ..." and "8 - ..." I think what is causing your crash my be found there...

Comment: I think when the qrcode scanner reads the text it stucks with the %20 which is a space and so it becomes null at that point.

Comment: I don't understand? And sorry for the confusion about the requested screenshots... haha I meant could you actually click the ones saying "6 -[Scan readerView:......" and "7 -..." and "8 -..." and post screenshots of the code it brings ups (or post the code)

Comment: Post your code for the `Scan readerView:didReadSymbols:fromImage:` method.

Comment: Buddy, There is nothing to do with the URL, It should be something to do with your code when you get the result from the ZBar lib, if you want to make sure, please scan below QR with ZBar sample app. http://qrfree.kaywa.com/?l=1&s=8&d=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.winlogisticsmedia.com%2Fimages%2Fbigkmr%2520end%2520sale.jpg

Comment: Could you please add the code of "- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info" function? then we can have a look whats going on.

Comment: One more thing @Prasad...other links are working good if the space(%20) has nothing to do with it.

Comment: - (void) readerView: (ZBarReaderView*) view
     didReadSymbols: (ZBarSymbolSet*) syms
          fromImage: (UIImage*) img
{
     for(ZBarSymbol *sym in syms) {
     resultText= sym.data;
     NSLog(resultText);
     break;       
    }
 if([resultText hasPrefix:@"http"])
    {        
        if([defaultaction isEqualToString:@"auto"]){
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:resultText];
        if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])            
            NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
        }
}

Comment: I tried doing resultText= [NSString stringWithFormat:sym.data]; then I tried logging NSLog, I got 
"http://www.winlogisticsmedia.com/images/bigkmr        0.000000e+00nd(null)ale.jpg"

Comment: Thank you all...the problem lies in NSString as I am expecting from the very beginning. so I changed the type to UITextView and hide that and take the results from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue. My app would crash when I would log the `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject` stringValue.

My original code that would crash:

```
NSLog("%@", [machineReadableCodeObject stringValue]);
```

Once I decoded the stringValue with `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` it does not crash anymore:

```
NSString* decodedValue = [[machineReadableCodeObject stringValue] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog("%@", decodedValue);
```